# I want to make a function that get the names of it caller for an array of radio buttons c#

Tags: c#, arrays, windows, function, radio-button

I'm very new to c# and programming overall. my problem is I have an array of radio buttons with the names of the users that the program already knows about and I want it so when a user clicks on them the name/text of that radio button appears on a certain textbox this is the code I use to make the radio buttons

```
foreach (string user in Registerd_Users)
        {
            string name = "Something it doesn't matter how this part works don't worry about it :)";
           
            buttonArray[i] = new RadioButton();
            buttonArray[i].Size = new Size(110, 21);
            buttonArray[i].Location = new Point(29, (44+(i*20)));
            buttonArray[i].Name = name;
            buttonArray[i].Text = name;
            this.Controls.Add(buttonArray[i]);
            i++;
```

so if anyone can explain to me how to solve this problem I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a handler for some suitable event of each RB like CheckedChanged and when it occurs, set the textbox Text if the RB has been checked, something like:

```
buttonArray[i].CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>
  { if(sender is RadioButton r && r.Checked) _someTextbox.Text = r.Text; }
```

We test if the rb is checked because CheckedChanged also fires for the RB that was unchecked when the new one checked

If you're looking for somewhere to store a large amount of varying text that doesn't show on the form, do it in the r.Tag, not the r.Text/r.Name

Comment: thanks for answering as I said I'm very new to programming. so can you please tell me what "r" is in RadioButton r/r.Checked/....?
@caius-jard

Comment: It's the radiobutton. It used to be that in c# you wrote two statements for safe code: `var r = sender as RadioButton; if(r != null && r.Checked) textbox.Text = r.Text;` but now you can do `x is Type y` to test if x is the type , and cast it, and store it in variable y so you can use it. If you want, go the old way: `(sender, e) =>  if(((RadioButton)sender).Checked) textbox.Text = ((RadioButton)sender).Text;` it's just a bit more messy

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast

Comment: @Charlieface Because I want to use r again, twice, so I use the `is` to create it, read Checked and then read Text. See the comment above yours